# Reading image file from excelsheet cell through Apache POI library

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

can any one plz tell me how to read an image  from an excel sheet cell through Apache POI .Actually my code works when the cell content is text type but when cell content is an image , it does not read the image to Cell class object and my cell class object takes it as blank data. plz help me guys....

Answer (score 1):

```
 List lst = workbook.getAllPictures();
    for (Iterator it = lst.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        PictureData pict = (PictureData)it.next();
        String ext = pict.suggestFileExtension();
        byte[] data = pict.getData();
        if (ext.equals("jpeg")){
          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("pict.jpg");
          out.write(data);
          out.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this really complete? ;) the question was about reading the picture element of a given cell and not just all the pictures attached to the workbook. So you need to fiddle around with X/HSSFPicture shapes and get the PictureData and MimeType (i.e. jpeg) from there ...